# Why do I get a duplicate declaration in same scope warning in an if/elsif tree?

Tags: perl

Why does the following code warn? $match is scoped to the if block and not the containing while block.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

use IO::All;

my $file = io($ARGV[0])->tie;
my $regex = qr//;

while (my $line = <$file>) {
  if (my ($match) = $line =~ $regex) {
    ...
  }
  elsif (my ($match) = $line =~ $regex) {
    ...
  }
  say $match;
}
```

---

```
C:\>perl testwarn.pl test.log
"my" variable $match masks earlier declaration in same scope at testwarn.pl line 15.
Global symbol "$match" requires explicit package name at testwarn.pl line 18.
Execution of testwarn.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

As expected, it complains that $match is not defined at line 18, but it also complains about the redeclaration of $match in the if blocks. Version is slightly out of date but not horribly so; and it's the most recent Strawberry version:

```
This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
```

Comment: why can't you define your $match variable before if block?

Comment: Because I want it scoped to the if block, not to the while block. It's simultaneously complaining that I'm redefining it in the if () check which suggests it's defined to the while {} block; while also complaining if I try using it later on in the while block. Just trying to make sure I understand the internals correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The scope of the first `$match` declaration is the entire `if-elsif-else` block. That lets you do things like this:

```
if ( (my $foo = some_value()) < some_other_value() ) {
    do_something();
} elsif ($foo < yet_another_value()) { # same $foo as in the if() above
    do_something_else();
} else {
    warn "\$foo was $foo\n";   # same $foo
}   # now $foo goes out of scope
print $foo;   # error under 'use strict' => $foo is now out of scope
```

If we were to declare `my $foo` anywhere else in this block, including in the `elsif (...)` clause, that would be a duplicate declaration in the same scope, and we'd get a warning message.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite: `if (my $foo) { my $foo }` doesn't warn. `if` creates two scopes: one for the entire statement (including the conditions) and one for each body block. The second scope is a child of the first, so the "then" block can see variables declared in the condition.

Answer (score 4):

Because a variable declared in the an `if` test is visible to the whole `if`/`elsif`/`else` statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub test {
    if (my $arg = shift) {
        print "$arg is true\n";
    } else {
        print defined $arg ? $arg : "undef", " is false\n";
    }
}

test undef;
test 0;
test 0.0;
test "0.0";
test 1
```

Answer (score 1):

this block

```
if (my ($match) = $line =~ $regex) {
...
elsif (my ($match) = $line =~ $regex) {
```

scopes `$match` to the if/else block and not to the while loop. And yet you are referencing it from the while block.

move it here

```
my $match;
if ($match = ($line =~ $regex)) {
```

Comment: If it's scoped to the complaining block, why does it die "Global symbol "$match" requires explicit package name at testwarn.pl line 18." when I try accessing it in the enclosing block? It should have issues with one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Yeah, dumb copy paste mistake

Answer (score 1):

`if` creates a lexical scope for the entire statement, and another lexical scope for each block (curlies).

In the following, each letter represents the span of a lexical scope:

```
A
if (B) {
   C
} elsif (B) {
   D
} else {
   E
}
A
```

Defining two variables with the same name in the same lexical scope results in the «"my" variable %s masks earlier declaration in same scope» warning.

Using a variable that wasn't declared in a lexical scope or an ancestral lexical scope results in the «Global symbol "%s" requires explicit package name» error.

- Lexical scopes "C", "D" and "E" are children of lexical scope "B".
- Lexical scope "B" is a child of lexical scope "A".

Answer (score -1):

This warning can be suppressed by including

```
no warnings qw/misc/;
```

in the containing block. When doing so, it will not warn about the redeclaration but will still die when attempting to access the variable outside of the if blocks.

Comment: Turning off warnings is a poor substitute for understanding what is going on.  And it doesn't die when you mask a variable in the same scope, it just warns.

Comment: The say dies when trying to use $match outside of the if-elsif-else statement. And if I didn't agree with you re: turning off warnings I wouldn't have posted the question here in the first place.